# How do I negate an asterisk in a java regex?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to create a regex that helps Eclipse's search find all lines that contain `start(` except for ones that are comment lines.

That is, find lines like:

```
 is not sufficient because it doesn't guarantee that start(b) is
```

But **not** lines like:

```
 * is not sufficient because it doesn't guarantee that start(b) is
```

I have been able to come up with the regex `(\s*?)(?!\*)(.*)(start\()(.*$)` but it finds *both* lines.

How do I exclude the line that starts with `*` (possibly after some whitespace) and include lines that don't have that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a line beginning with whitespace, it would be possible for the `\s*?` to match zero whitespaces, then the `(?!\*)` to match a whitespace, and the `.*` trailer to match the rest of the line including asterisk.

A solution would be to put the leading-whitespace preamble inside the negated clause:

```
^(?!\s*\*).*start\(.*$
```

Alternatively you could use a possessive quantifier to eat all the whitespaces and never backtrack:

```
^\s*+(?!\*).*start\(.*$
```

Comment: `^(?!\s*\*).*start\(.*$` works. It even produces a *match* (in addition to a *find*, which the `[^\*]` form below didn't). +1 already.

Comment: Ditto for `^\s*+(?!\*).*start\(.*$`.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\s*+(?=[^\*]).*?start\(
```

`^` is the start of the line

`\s*+` is greedy about consuming whitespace

`(?=` is a lookahead - it matches a position, but not any text. This lets the thing you are searching for be the first thing on the line.

`[^\*]` is any character that isn't a *

`)` end the lookahead

`.*?` lazy match any old rubbish

`start\(` or whatever else you want to find

Comment: This one works. I just tested it. I think what I was missing is the `[^\*]` (vs. `(?!\*)`). I need to educate myself more about this. +1 for now, as it looks like there are several good answers but I can only accept one.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this `^\s*[^\*]+.*start\(.*$`

Comment: This needs a little work. Whitespace would need to be added to the negated character class so that it can't backtrack into leading whitespaces. Asterisks elsewhere in the line are apparently acceptable, so the `+` would be superfluous... a corner case would be a line starting with `start(`. To get around that you could go with `^\s*([^*\s].*)?start\(.*$`.

Comment: Sorry but this produces the same (incorrect) results as my `(\s*?)(?!\*)(.*)(start\()(.*$)`. Thanks for the attempt though.